# Thumbnails in a brick style instead of grid - how to do this?

Tags: css, gallery, thumbnails

Is there any jQuery or other plugin which let me display my thumbnails like that:

http://hellocute.tumblr.com/archive

I know, example is cool :). Anyway this is cool brick style which displays images not in columns, which would be easy to do, it displays them in rows, so next row is starting in the highest available position, not in the first column for example.. That's pretty cool. Also works for any window size which is double cool.

Anyone know how to do this ? I checked their code but it's difficult to find the answer there.

Was trying to google: css brick style, thumnails brick display, js brick photos

Nothing interested found.

THX

Comment: The link gives a 403. And that's pretty damn NSFW.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl: Oh well - used to be scantily-clad young ladies. @user584625: **If the linked content might offend your old-maiden great-aunt, please say so in your post**. Not everyone appreciates Not-Safe-For-Work material, esp. not at work, in open-plan offices and on monitored connections. While I'm not personally offended, I'm not willing to bet the same of all my coworkers.

Comment: Whatever you do...shortening the URL to just http://theladsmag.tumblr.com is DEFINITELY NSFW! You've been warned.

Also, might the display be like the new google image search results page?

Comment: ok, sorry about that, it was just first tumblr archive page i've ever seen.

Answer (score 7):

[jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) is probably what you are looking for.